# async operations using Combine and SwiftUI

Tags: asynchronous, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to figure out how to work with async operations using Combine and SwiftUI.

For example, I have a `HealthKitManager` class that, among other things, handles requesting health store authorisation…

```
final class HealthKitManager {

    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case notAvailable
        case authorisationError(Swift.Error)
    }

    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

        func getHealthKitData(for objects: Set<HKObjectType>, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) {

        guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
            completion(.failure(.notAvailable))
            return
        }

        self.healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: objects) { completed, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(.authorisationError(error)))
                }
                completion(.success(completed))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is used as follows…

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let healthKitManager = HealthKitManager()

    @State var showNextView = false
    @State var showError = false
    @State var hkError: Error?

    let objectTypes = Set([HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodGlucose)!])

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: NextView(), isActive: $showNextView) {
                Button("Show Next View") {
                    self.getHealthKitData()
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Content View")
        }.alert(isPresented: $showError) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(hkError?.localizedDescription ?? ""), dismissButton: .cancel())
        }
    }

    func getHealthKitData() {
        self.healthKitManager.getHealthKitData(for: self.objectTypes) { result in
            switch result {
            case let .success(complete):
                self.showNextView = complete
            case let .failure(error):
                self.hkError = error
                self.showError = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is use Combine rather than a `Result` closure. I'm guessing something like this…

```
final class HealthKitManager: ObservableObject {

    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case notAvailable
        case authorisationError(Swift.Error)
    }

    @Published var authorisationResult: Result<Bool, Error>?

     let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

    func getHealthKitData(for objects: Set<HKObjectType>) {

        guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
            self.authorisationResult = .failure(.notAvailable)
            return
        }

        self.healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: objects) { completed, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    self.authorisationResult = .failure(.authorisationError(error))
                    return
                }
                self.authorisationResult = .success(completed)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then it's unclear how to bind to the values for `NavigationLink(isActive:)` and `alert(isPresented:)`, and to get the error.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var healthKitManager = HealthKitManager()

    let objectTypes = Set([HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodGlucose)!])

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: NextView(), isActive: ????) { // How do I get this
                Button("Show Next View") {
                    self.healthKitManager.getHealthKitData(for: self.objectTypes)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Content View")
        }.alert(isPresented: ????) { // or this
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(????.localizedDescription ?? ""), dismissButton: .cancel()) // or this
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that `@Published var authorisationResult: Result<Bool, Error>?` isn't correct? 
Should I be using `Future / Promise`, something else?

---

*Update*

I found there's another way to present an alert…

```
.alert(item: self.$error) { error in
        Alert(title: Text(error.localizedDescription))
```

which means I don't need the Bool for `showError` (it just requires the `Error` object to be `Identifiable`)

Comment: `@Published` provides you a publisher and has automatic integration with SwiftUI view refresh via `@ObservedObject` dynamic property. You can use anything, but think about *pros & cons*. Is it the goal to make simple things complex?

Answer (score 5):

I like having `result` as you did in second variant

```
@Published var authorisationResult: Result<Bool, Error>?
```

so the possible approach for usage can be as follow

```
NavigationLink(destination: NextView(), isActive: 
         Binding<Bool>.ifSuccess(self.healthKitManager.authorisationResult)) {
    Button("Show Next View") {
        self.healthKitManager.getHealthKitData(for: self.objectTypes)
    }
}.navigationBarTitle("Content View")
```

where some convenient extension

```
extension Binding {
    static func ifSuccess<E>(_ result: Result<Bool, E>?) -> Binding<Bool> where E: Error {
        Binding<Bool>(
            get: {
                guard let result = result else { return false }
                switch result {
                 case .success(true):
                    return true
                 default:
                    return false
            }
        }, set: { _ in })
    }
}
```

the variant for `error` can be done in similar way.

Answer (score 3):

### Revised my answer to be based on [@Asperi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60411013):

```
extension Result {
    func getFailure() -> Failure? {
        switch self {
        case .failure(let er):
            return er
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    func binding<B>(
         success successClosure: (@escaping (Success) -> B),
         failure failureClosure: @escaping (Failure) -> B) -> Binding<B> {
        return Binding<B>(
        get: {
            switch self {
            case .success(let value):
                return successClosure(value)
            case .failure(let failure):
                return failureClosure(failure)
            }
        }, set: { _ in })
    }

    func implicitBinding(failure failureClosure: @escaping (Failure) -> Success) -> Binding<Success> {
        return binding(success: { $0 }, failure: failureClosure)
    }
}

class HealthKitManager: ObservableObject {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case authorisationError(Swift.Error)
        case notAvailable
    }

    @Published var authorisationResult = Result<Bool, Error>.failure(.notAvailable)

    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

    func getHealthKitData(for objects: Set<HKObjectType>) {
        guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
            self.authorisationResult = .failure(.notAvailable)
            return
        }

        self.healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: objects) { completed, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    self.authorisationResult = .failure(.authorisationError(error))
                    return
                }

                self.authorisationResult = .success(completed)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var healthKitManager = HealthKitManager()

    let objectTypes = Set([HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodGlucose)!])

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: NextView(),
                           isActive: healthKitManager.authorisationResult.implicitBinding(failure: { _ in false })) {
                Button("Show Next View") {
                    self.healthKitManager.getHealthKitData(for: self.objectTypes)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Content View")
        }.alert(isPresented: healthKitManager.authorisationResult.binding(success: { _ in false }, failure: { _ in true })) {
                let message = healthKitManager.authorisationResult.getFailure()?.localizedDescription ?? ""
                return Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(message), dismissButton: .cancel()) // or this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That would definitely work, but having separate values for `hasAuthorizationError`, `authorizationError` and `isAuthorized` doesn't seem right somehow… especially as all 3 are covered by the single Result type. Also this class may be used for other async operations, so adding 3 extra `@Published` vars for each op seems a lot. I was hoping Combine would have some better way of handling this.